# Dictionary key and deque, dont work second popleft or first pop. python

Tags: python, deque

I am a begginer in python, i have a dictionary that has the key name and value as a deque, when i add in my deque it works, but when i try to withdraw with popleft only the first one works

```
from collections import deque

class EmployeePoint:

    dic = {}

    def __init__(self,name,point):

        self.name = name
        self.point = point


people1 = EmployeePoint("Rafael","18")
people2 = EmployeePoint("Rafael","19")
people3 = EmployeePoint("Rafael","20")

EmployeePoint.dic["Rafael"] = deque([people1])
EmployeePoint.dic["Rafael"].append([people2])
EmployeePoint.dic["Rafael"].append([people3])


print EmployeePoint.dic["Rafael"].popleft().point
print EmployeePoint.dic["Rafael"].popleft().point
```

**Track back:**

18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in 
    print EmployeePoint.dic["Rafael"].popleft().point
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'point'

Comment: You're appending a list of employees. Change `append([people2])` to `append(people2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing the ***deque*** is fine with `deque([people1])` but you shouldn't be appending a list with one item in it (i.e. `[people2]` instead `.append(people2)`

```
from collections import deque

class EmployeePoint:

    dic = {}

    def __init__(self,name,point):

        self.name = name
        self.point = point


people1 = EmployeePoint("Rafael","18")
people2 = EmployeePoint("Rafael","19")
people3 = EmployeePoint("Rafael","20")

EmployeePoint.dic["Rafael"] = deque([people1])
EmployeePoint.dic["Rafael"].append(people2)
EmployeePoint.dic["Rafael"].append(people3)


print (EmployeePoint.dic["Rafael"].popleft().point)
print (EmployeePoint.dic["Rafael"].popleft().point) 
# py3 print paretheses
```

Output:

> 18
>
> 19